# SetEditable does not work in the latest Android version

Tags: c#, android, android-edittext

There are multiple questions already asked about how to use SetEditable to true and false and those questions have answers that have worked.

But the latest Android version seems to have SetEditable deprecated.

This is my code:

```
            EditText mEmailEdit = (EditText) View.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
        mEmailEdit.SetEditable(false);
```

The EditText `txtEmail`is in a pop up box.

I get an error in the line `mEmailEdit.SetEditable(false);` with the word "false" underlined in red.

What am I doing wrong?  And if SetEditable is indeed deprecated for EditText, what are the available workarounds?

Thank you in advance.

Uttam

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47901457/8117793 Hope this will Help

Comment: My mistake in saying I was using "SetEditable" while it should have been "Editable.

However, SetFocusable(false) also does not work.

I changed the code as advised to:

            mEmailEdit.SetFocusable(false);

But I get an error with use of false.

the tip reads as:
struct System.Boolean to be added.

Argument 1: Cannot convert from bool to Android.Views.Viewfocusability
---End tip---

I even defined:             bool false_value = Boolean.Parse("False");

and used the variable "false_value" (without quotes) in place of false - but that too did not work.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mEmailEdit.setFocusable(false)` instaed of `mEmailEdit.setEditable(false);` in **Java**

in **Xamarim** or **C#** use `mEmailEdit.Focusable(false)`

the Attribute `editable` is **Deprecated**.

By Changing the FocusaFeatureture you can Achieve the effect of `editable` in Android. try this . Hope It will Work Fine

Answer (score 0):

### Below Android2.2

You can use `android:editable="false"`.

### Above Android2.2

Like @Tomin B has said, the `editable` has been deprecated.

You can use `android:focusable="false"` to achieve it. That means the `EditText` can't get the focus, so user won't input text.

And there is no [SetEditable](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.EditText/) method, even in [TextView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.TextView/) class which is the parent of `EditText`.